# Where and how do you start a business?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Where can you find a business? And how do you start a business?

Answer (score 1):

You need to complete a specific mission before you can purchase properties. From [the wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Properties_in_GTA_V):

> The ability to purchase properties is unlocked after completing Trevor's mission **Nervous Ron**

Once you have done that, businesses can be found at various locations. Following table pulled from a [GTA wiki](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Properties_in_GTA_V). This info is supported by [other sources](http://www.gamezone.com/originals/gta-5-cheats-complete-list-of-properties-you-can-buy).

[image]

Finally, when you approach a property which can be purchased, a prompt to purchase it will appear in the upper right.

[image]